Clarification on Blomer and Seifert reduction from CVP to SIVP
In "On the Complexity of Computing Short Linearly Independent Vectors and Short Bases in a Lattice" by Blomer and Seifert, they show that the SIVP is NP-complete by reducing the Closest Vector problem (CVP) to SIVP. I have some minor confusion about the reduction.
They start with an instance $(L,v,r)$ of CVP with $L$ the lattice with a basis $B$, $v$ the vector and $r$ the distance of $v$ to $L$. And define the following:

$D = \max \{ r+1, \lceil n^{n/2} \det(L) \rceil \}$ with $n$ the rank of $L$;
a lattice $M$ defined by the basis $\begin{pmatrix} B & v \\ 0 & D \end{pmatrix}$;

They show that $CVP(L,v,r)$ if and only if $SIVP(M,\sqrt{r^2+D^2})$. As I understand, the reduction should be polynomial time. But I don't understand due to the computation of $\sqrt{r^2+D^2}$ which does not look like to be polynomial to me.
A possibility would that the problem actually solved is something like $SIVP^2(M,r^2+D^2)$ with $SIVP^2$ being the same as SIVP but using the square norm instead of the norm. Or is it something else?

$\sqrt{r^2 + D^2}$ can be computed in polynomial time with good precision. For instance, you can apply Netwon's iteration method.

But then, you would need to show that the required precision does not need to be too high, right?

As mentioned in the paper,

Strictly speaking, to obtain well-defined decision problems the bound $r$ in the definitions above has to be a rational number. In our constructions and proofs naturally these bounds are square roots of rational numbers. It is always straightforward to resolve the problems caused by real numbers. To keep the notation simple, for the rest of the paper, we will ignore these problems.

So, we will consider $L \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^n, v \in \mathbb{Q}^n, r \in \mathbb{Q}$. By multiplying with an appropriate integer (whose bit-size is polynomial in the input size), we can work with $L \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n, v \in \mathbb{Z}^n, r \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Due to the integrality, either $\|v - L\| \leq r$ or $\|v - L\| \geq \sqrt{r^2+1}$. Therefore, it suffices to find an approximation $r'$ of $\sqrt{r^2 + D^2}$ such that $\sqrt{r^2 + D^2} \leq r' < \sqrt{(r^2 + 1) + D^2}$. Observe that for any integer $k$,
$$\sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k} = \frac{(\sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k})(\sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k})}{\sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k}} \geq \dfrac{1}{O(k)}$$
So, we can find an $r'$ using Newton's iteration method upto a precision of $\frac{1}{O(r^2 + D^2)}$ in $poly(\log(r), \log(D))$ time. Therefore, the entire reduction is polynomial time in the input size.
